# How can ios detect gps tampering on xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

How can ios detect gps tampering on xcode, it comes with “simulate location” on xcode, is there a way to detect gps tampering caused by it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No,  you cannot trust a device you don't physically control.  It can lie.

Comment: I have added the questions below. I just want to detect address spoofing in xcode, which is not implemented through hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The debug output area of xcode has a button called "simulate location" which allows you to simulate the location of different countries, and when you use CLLocation to get the location it will output the location of the country selected by the simulator.

```
CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
manager.delegate = self;
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[manager startUpdatingLocation];

if( [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] ) {
    CLLocation *location = [manager location];  //maybe other country
    NSLog(@"%@", location);
}
```